# Linux Shell Script to filter git status command

Tags: linux, shell, substring, trim

What I want is a script shell that iterates through each line of `git status` command,
finds files that were modified and for each file path run a given command.

So to be more specific,
Given this output:

```
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

        renamed:    ASCourses-UI-vechi/src/application/Chat.fxml -> ASCourses-UI                                                                                                                                   /src/main/resources/fxml/ChatController.fxml

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   ASCourses-UI-vechi/bin/.gitignore
        modified:   ASCourses-UI-vechi/bin/application/Chat.css
        modified:   ASCourses-UI-vechi/bin/application/Chat.fxml
        modified:   ASCourses-UI-vechi/bin/application/ChatController$1.class
        modified:   ASCourses-UI-vechi/bin/application/ChatController$2.class
        modified:   ASCourses-UI-vechi/bin/application/ChatController$3$1.class
        modified:   ASCourses-UI-vechi/bin/application/ChatController$3.class
        modified:   ASCourses-UI-vechi/bin/application/ChatController$4.class
        modified:   ASCourses-UI-vechi/bin/application/ChatController$5.class
```

I want for each file that was modified and starts with *ASCourses-UI-vechi* to run `git checkout file_path`

What I got so far is this:

```
#!/bin/bash
(IFS='
'
for x in ` git status | grep -E 'modified.*ASCourses-UI-vechi' | sed -e 's/^[[:space:]]*//' -e 's/[[:space:]]*$//'`;
do
echo $x;
done)
```

So currently I filter and trim output and get this:

```
modified:   ASCourses-UI-vechi/bin/.gitignore
modified:   ASCourses-UI-vechi/bin/application/Chat.css
modified:   ASCourses-UI-vechi/bin/application/Chat.fxml
modified:   ASCourses-UI-vechi/bin/application/ChatController$1.class
modified:   ASCourses-UI-vechi/bin/application/ChatController$2.class
modified:   ASCourses-UI-vechi/bin/application/ChatController$3$1.class
modified:   ASCourses-UI-vechi/bin/application/ChatController$3.class
modified:   ASCourses-UI-vechi/bin/application/ChatController$4.class
modified:   ASCourses-UI-vechi/bin/application/ChatController$5.class
```

Problem is I don't know how to substring from first occurrence of ASCourses string until the end of the whole string

Answer (score 0):

Using awk:

```
[user@user ~]$ echo "modified:   ASCourses-UI-vechi/bin/.gitignore" | awk '{print $2}'
ASCourses-UI-vechi/bin/.gitignore
```

Using sed:

```
[user@user ~]$ echo "modified:   ASCourses-UI-vechi/bin/.gitignore" | sed 's/modified:\s\+//'
ASCourses-UI-vechi/bin/.gitignore
```